# Crear archivos ejecutables multiplataforma con QT y Netbeans

Tags: linux, netbeans, windows, qt, compilar

Acabo de empezar mis primeros pasos con QT utilizando Netbeans en mi máquina con Ubuntu.

Al terminar mi primer (pequeñisimo) proyecto, me gustaría crear un archivo ejecutable del mismo. Consigo hacerlo sin problemas para plataformas UNIX, pero no encuentro la forma de obtener un ejecutable para Windows o OSx.

Me preguntaba:

¿Es posible seleccionar una plataforma objetivo en Netbeans a la hora de compilar el proyecto? En mi caso, como he dicho, obtengo este fichero de aplicación pero sólo para UNIX.

¿Necesito utilizar alguna otra herramienta?

Muchísimas gracias de antemano por vuestra orientación¡

---

**Edición**

Tras buscar algo de información acerca de como hacer esta misma operación con Netbeans, no he encontrado gran cosa para compilar estas aplicaciones. Sin embargo, si he encontrado algo similar para hacerlo con las aplicaciones programadas en Java.

Al igual que es posible hacerlo con Java, me preguntaba si sería posible hacer lo mismo con las aplicaciones basadas en QT, como es mi caso.

No se si esto será que tengo algún fallo de conceptos o que me estoy saltando algún paso a la hora de configurar el compilador de C++ en Netbeans.

Gracias.

Comment: que lenguaje usas? desde linux es imposible que compiles y te salga el .exe, tienes q instalar todo en windows y luego compilar el mismo codigo.

Comment: Justo he leido el post que mencionas antes de publicar, pero no me resuelve la duda que tengo.  Respecto a los lenguages que uso, en esta ocasión la aplicación está basada en QT y desarrollada usando Netbeans corriendo en una máquina con Ubuntu.

Comment: @RenatoA. Desde Linux **es perfectamente posible generar ejecutables para Windows**. Buscad *info* sobre [Compilación cruzada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilador_cruzado). En Ubuntu, el paquete es `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`. Aparte de eso, el tema es un *pelín* amplio :-)

Comment: como te dije, no se que lenguaje estas usando, solo me dices los nombres de los programas q usas... lo cual es informacion redundante. si es java, no nesesitas preocuparte por eso, java tiene la jvm q hacen q corras tu programa hasta en un coche. si es c++ entonces cambia la cosa

Comment: Perdona Renato. Estoy utilizando C++ (disculpa la confusión). ¿Cuanto me "complica" la vida en ese caso? @Trauma. Muchas gracias por el apunte. Voy a mirar sobre ello a ver que encuentro. ¿Existe alguna aplicación, suite o similar, que realice este tipo de compilaciones de forma "automatizada"? Disculpad mi ignorancia. Muchisimas gracias a todos.

Comment: @JavierGonzalezMoncayo Sobre *suites*, ni idea. Yo soy de los *antiguos*, uso `Makefiles`. La verdad es que hace **mucho** tiempo que no *juego* con esas cosas. En aquella época, había que copiar `.dll` de Windows a Linux y hacer algunas *cosillas* mas. Hoy día, creo que se ha simplificado bastante. Instalar los paquetes `mingw-XXX` necesarios e ir probando. Ya irás preguntando las dudas que te vallan saliendo :-)

Comment: @JavierGonzalezMoncayo Por cierto, comparar **Java** con **C++** creo que es un delito grave, con penas de cárcel en algunos paises ;-)

Comment: @Trauma, acabo de pasar un rato leyendo cosas. Tienes toda la razón. Espero que donde vivo no sea un delito tan grande. Gracias a todos. Voy a continuar con el experimento

Comment: No se mucho de QT en Netbeans. Pero alguna vez lleve openGL en `QT creator` y el profesor nos comento que había que copiar y pegar el código en la plataforma de destino y si eran las mismas versiones, solo bastaba con compilar de nuevo. Ahora yo he usado `QT creator` en mac y si vi opciones para compilar en linux, windows, mac hace años y vi que traía opciones para symbian, y ahora se que trae para iOS y android. Pero te soy sincero solo use la compilación de mac. Yo te recomendaría dejar de usar netbeans y empezar a usar `QT creator`.